# Get values from array google books

Tags: php, arrays, rest

The response of the google api is like this

```
{
 "kind": "books#volumes",
 "totalItems": 1956,
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
   "id": "P_zMW3EHnTEC",
   "etag": "BWKRqUEh9VU",
   "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/P_zMW3EHnTEC",
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "The 48 Laws Of Power",
    "authors":
```

Now the main array is $bookBatch and in that items is an array. items array contains volumeInfo array. And in that volumeInfo there is title. 
I want to get title . So I wrote following foreach loop

```
foreach($bookBatch['items'] as $row)
    {
    foreach($row['volumeInfo'] as $volumeinfo)
       {

echo $volumeinfo['title'];

       }    
    }
```

But I am getting output like this

```
TP2TB0ehhhTS2YBpehhhTP2TB0ehhhTAN2TB0ehhhPIT1IB0ehhhP2SB0ehhhPP1TBpehhhPW1SBpehhhSTP2HB0ehhhPAP2IB0ehhh
```

Instead I should be getting the title like The 48 Laws of Power

EDIT 1

```
 $query="power";
    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=".$query;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $bookBatch = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $bookBatch = json_decode($bookBatch, true);
```

Comment: It'd help you can show us the entire JSON response. Can you paste it in http://pastebin.com ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Tjsp1fKB

Comment: That looks like the print_r output. Show us the JSON response.

Comment: Now it is ok? http://pastebin.com/index/Tjsp1fKB

Comment: This is what my developer says JSON is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data looks like the following

```
$json = '{
 "kind": "books#volumes",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
   "id": "_ojXNuzgHRcC",
   "etag": "OTD2tB19qn4",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/_ojXNuzgHRcC",
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "Flowers",
    "authors": [
     "Vijaya Khisty Bodach"
    ]
  }}]}';

$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($data['items'] as $item)
{
    echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'];

    // This will show the Authors names
    echo implode(', ', $item['volumeInfo']['authors']);
}
```

Comment: Show us how you create `$bookBatch`

Comment: I edited the question. I get response. The pastebin link is http://pastebin.com/Tjsp1fKB

Comment: It looks like you're parsing JSON with the `$assoc` param TRUE. See my updated answer.

Comment: The author information outputted by this code would be different from the original author.

Comment: You were using a nested foreach just minutes ago, and now you've just copied my answer, changing the variable name and adding `implode()`. How original. :)

Comment: Didn't copy your answer, I improved it based on yours. And I answered 42mins ago BTW :)